# ERROR: mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, git, heroku

I tried to post my web app on Heroku but while pushing I got this error I am in trouble due to this error from last 1 week nowhere I am getting the answer.

[image]

The output is:

```
$ heroku rename codingisjoyful
Renaming codingpassion to codingisjoyful... done
https://codingisjoyful herokuapp.com/ https://git.heroku.com/codingisjoyful.git
Git remote heroku updated

$ git push heroku master Enumerating objects: 1279, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1279/1279), done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1266/1266), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1279/1279). 11.63 MiB 1.90 MiB/s. done. Total 1279 (delta 116). reused 0 (delta 0). pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done. remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: Python app detected
remote: Installing python-3.6.12
remote: remote: - Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2 ----> Installing SQLite3
remote: --- Installing requirements with pip 
ERROR: mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.wh] is not a supported wheel on this platform.
remote: Push rejected. failed to compile Python app.
Push failed
master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) failed to mush some refs to "htts//git.heroku. con/cotingssjayfol.git
```

Comment: Please add more information of what you are doing, what you have tried and please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems clear:

A pre-receive hook on heroku side is rejecting your push because it fails to compile your application.

It fails because mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel.

It is not a supported wheel because, as explained [in this article](https://medium.com/@isuru.is77/django-mysql-client-installation-on-windows-7cbf70f3f9cf):

> you may try install a wrong version of wheel, carefuly chose the one suit your environment e.g python version, 32bit/64bit need same with your python bit version not system